# ruby - transform_value of a specific key[1]

Tags: ruby, compare, distinct-values

I am trying for each row to compare the fx value of each corresponding name;
So the outcome should be : `diff={"name"=>"XPT", "fx"=>"1.1315313597682419"}`
or rounded before having to be compared _ if it is easier to get it that way : `diff={"name"=>"XPT", "fx"=>"1.13153"}`

So far I have a TypeError (no implicit conversion of String into Integer) with the following:

```rb
def compare_values
    diff = {}
    a = [{"src"=>"reportStack"},
    {"name"=>"XPT", "fx"=>"1.1315313597682419"},
    {"name"=>"XAU", "fx"=>"27.0165670831070071"},
    {"name"=>"XAG", "fx"=>"8.4192241535397429"}]

    b = [{"src"=>"reportOverflow"},
    {"name"=>"XPT", "fx"=>"1.13163"},
    {"name"=>"XAU", "fx"=>"27.0165670831070071"},
    {"name"=>"XAG", "fx"=>"8.4192"}]

    b.each do |b_row|
       a.each do |a_row|
          b.each do |k,v|
            diff = k if a_row['name'].value == e_row['name'].value && a_row['fx'].value.to_f != a_row['fx'].value.to_f
          end
      end
    end
end
```

Could anyone please give a tip how to handle this pickle?

Comment: How about this one? `diff = {}
a.each do |a_row|
  b.each do |b_row|
    if a_row['name'] == b_row['name'] && a_row['fx'] != b_row['fx']
      diff = {"name" => a_row['name'], "fx" => a_row['fx']}
    end
  end
end
puts diff`

Comment: Please provide an example that people (who are trying to help) can run locally and see what's wrong. What you provided so far does not result in `TypeError`.

Comment: @Greg 
I added this part to complete my code:
`def compare_values`
Tks

Comment: @Kamilo please run `irb` in your console, copy paste and make sure it reproduces the `TypeError` issue. The update is a step into the right direction, but the code does not result in the problem you're asking for, but `undefined local variable or method `e_file'`

Comment: `e_file` is not defined at all and `diff{} << k` is not valid Syntax. Please revise the question.

Comment: @Greg you are totally right, it is a mistake on my end, it should be: `b.each` as modified above.. Tks!!

Comment: @Kamilo you still have a variable `e_row` which has no definition and this condition `a_row['fx'].value.to_f != a_row['fx'].value.to_f` can never be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would begin by simplifying the data structures for both reportStack (a) and reportOverflow (b) into hashes, where the key is `name`, and the value is `fx`. This will allow us to compare key-value pairs without having to iterate through an array and checking each value.

```rb
report_stack = a.inject(Hash.new) do |memo, report_stack_entry|
  next memo unless report_stack_entry['name']

  memo[report_stack_entry['name']] = report_stack_entry['fx']
  memo
end

# report_stack => {"XPT"=>"1.1315313597682419", "XAU"=>"27.0165670831070071", "XAG"=>"8.4192241535397429"}

report_overflow = b.inject(Hash.new) do |memo, report_overflow_entry|
  next memo unless report_overflow_entry['name']

  memo[report_overflow_entry['name']] = report_overflow_entry['fx']
  memo
end

# report_overflow => {"XPT"=>"1.13163", "XAU"=>"27.0165670831070071", "XAG"=>"8.4192"}
```

I would then `.reject` over report_stack with a `!nil?`, `start_with?`, and `==` condition on the corresponding report_overflow key

```rb
diff = report_stack.reject do |name, fx|
  overflow_fx = report_overflow[name]

  !overflow_fx.nil? && (
    fx == overflow_fx ||
    fx.start_with?(overflow_fx)
  )
end

diff #=> {"XPT"=>"1.1315313597682419"}
```

If any additional comparison logic is required, you should be able to easily update the condition in the `.reject` block to do so.